# Android Getting file name and path from onActivityResult

Tags: android, file, path

What I am trying to achieve. I have a `button`, when the button is clicked the app opens a file picker and the user selects a file. The app then uses a `FileInputStream` to read the file and generates a `byte[]`. I have a `TextView` below the `button` which will then simply display the `byte[].length`. Here is the code in the `button.onClick()` event:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");

    requestFilePickerCode = parent.registerActivityResultListener(this);
    try
    {
        parent.startActivityForResult(intent, requestFilePickerCode);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(task.getParent(), "Please install a file manager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Now this code works and I have confirmed that it fires `onActivityResult` when the file is chosen. I simply print a `Log` to display `data.toString()` which produces the following output:

```
11-02 15:14:36.196 2535-2535/? V/class za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.utility.handlers.PebbleTypeHandlerBinary: -----> content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1
```

So it seems to be getting the selected file. When I run the app and I select a file it throws my custom error:

```
11-02 15:14:36.196 2535-2535/? E/class za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.utility.handlers.PebbleTypeHandlerBinary: -----> File does not exist
```

This obviously indicates that I am not getting the file. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    byte[] fileContent;

    // check that data is not null and assign to file if not null
    if (data != null)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String uriString = uri.toString();
        file = new File(uriString);

        Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> " + file.toString());

        // declare file input stream and read bytes
        // write to string variable to test and test output
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileContent = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            fin.read(fileContent);
            String test = new String(fileContent);
            Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "=====> " + test);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(task.getParent(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> File does not exist");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(task.getParent(), "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Error while reading the file");
        }
        finally
        {
            // close the file input stream to stop mem leaks
            try
            {
                if (fin != null)
                {
                    fin.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Error closing the stream");
            }
        }

        Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), data.toString());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Please can you guys review my code and help me to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it as follows:

I used `inputStream = task.getParent().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` to get an `InputStream`. Then used a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write to a byte[]. See code below.

```
@Override
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    byte[] fileContent;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try
    {
        inputStream = task.getParent().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if (inputStream != null)
        {
            fileContent = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            inputStream.read(fileContent);
            fileContent = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read;
            while((read=inputStream.read(fileContent))>-1) baos.write(fileContent,0,read);
            fileContent = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Input Stream: " + inputStream);
            Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Byte Array: " + fileContent.length);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Input Stream is null");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> File not found", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Error reading file", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inputStream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> Error reading file", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 5):

/* you can get just name and size with this method.

- use Cursor .
- Uri uri = data.getData();
- get data from onActivityResult()
  */;

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

```
    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    String size = Long.toString(cursor.getLong(sizeIndex));

    Toast.makeText(this, "name : "+name+"\nsize : "+size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

U can search converting `uri` to `filepath`.

`GetData()` retruns a uri.

But `new File()` need a `filepath` param;

Like this:

```
public static String getRealFilePath( final Context context, final Uri uri ) {
    if ( null == uri ) return null;
    final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    String data = null;
    if ( scheme == null )
        data = uri.getPath();
    else if ( ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equals( scheme ) ) {
        data = uri.getPath();
    } else if
( ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals( scheme ) ) {

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query( uri, new String[] { ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null );
        if ( null != cursor ) {
            if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {

int index = cursor.getColumnIndex( ImageColumns.DATA );
                if ( index > -1 ) {
                    data = cursor.getString( index );
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I have now changed the code to `   Uri uri = data.getData();
   String uriString = uri.getPath();
   file = new File(uriString);
   // String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
   Log.v(PebbleTypeHandlerBinary.class.toString(), "-----> " + uriString);`. This still throws File not found...

Comment: I have managed to change the code to get the path thanks but it still throws File not Found. The stack trace now prints the path as follows: 11-02 19:21:57.073 7506-7506/? V/class za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard.utility.handlers.PebbleTypeHandlerBinary: -----> /document/2

Comment: u cant get filepath simplely using uri.getPath()

Answer (score 0):

**1. File Name:**

You can get the file name with the following method:

```
    public static String getFileName(Context context, Uri uri) {
            String result = null;
            if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                try {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            if (result == null) {
                result = uri.getPath();
                int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
                if (cut != -1) {
                    result = result.substring(cut + 1);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

You will call it inside onActivityResult() and pass to it the context and uri. and you can find the uri through the intent you get from the onActivityResult which is mostly called "data", you will get the Uri from it like this:

```
data.data
```

which ".data" is the Uri.

Ex:

```
Utils.getFileName(this, data!!.data)
```

And finally it will return the file name as a String.


**2. File Path:**

Simply to get the file path you can get it from the data intent uri like this:

```
data!!.data!!.path.toString()
```

It will get you the path of the file as a String.